# Error using SQL loader

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sql-loader

I am trying to import data from .dat file to a table in oracle database, using **SQL loader**.

**control file:**

```
LOAD DATA
infile 'E:\labs\labs\lab_18_06.dat'
INTO TABLE INVENTORY.PRODUCT_ON_HAND
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(on_hand_id,
product_id,
quantity,
warehouse_city char(30),
last_update date(12) 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

**data file contains records like this one:**

```
5001,1001,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
```

**table in database:**

```
SQL> desc inventory.product_on_hand;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ON_HAND_ID                                NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 PRODUCT_ID                                         NUMBER(7)
 QUANTITY                                           NUMBER(5)
 WAREHOUSE_CITY                                     VARCHAR2(30)
 LAST_UPDATE                                        DATE
```

**I am getting the following error in the .log file:**

```
Record 1: Failed - Error in the table INVENTORY.PRODUCT_ON_HAND, column LAST_UPDATE.
ORA-01843: month not valid
```

Please help to sort out my issue!

UPDATE:

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-----------
06-OCT-2013
```

I set `nls_lang='american'` and `nls_date_format='DD-MON-YYYY'`, but this didn`t help/

**BAD FILE:**

```
5001,1001,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5002,1001,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5003,1001,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5004,1002,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5005,1002,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5006,1002,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5007,1003,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5008,1003,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5009,1003,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5010,1004,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5011,1004,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5012,1004,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5013,1005,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5014,1005,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5015,1005,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5016,1006,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5017,1006,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5018,1006,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5019,1007,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5020,1007,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5021,1007,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5022,1008,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5023,1008,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5024,1008,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5025,1009,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5026,1009,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5027,1009,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5028,1010,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5029,1010,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5030,1010,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5031,1010,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5032,1011,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5033,1011,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5034,1012,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5035,1012,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5036,1012,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5037,1013,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5038,1013,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5039,1014,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5040,1014,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5041,1015,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5042,1015,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5043,1015,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5044,1016,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5045,1016,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5046,1016,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5047,1017,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5048,1017,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
5049,1017,7,Orlando,01-FEB-2004
5050,1018,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004
5051,1018,7,Chicago,01-FEB-2004
```

Comment: What is your setting for NLS_LANG? `FEB` is not a valid month name in all languages.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I set american.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  yes it is

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I posted it, see changes in initial post.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
alter session set nls_date_language='american'; 

LOAD DATA
infile 'E:\labs\labs\lab_18_06.dat'
INTO TABLE INVENTORY.PRODUCT_ON_HAND
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(on_hand_id,
product_id,
quantity,
warehouse_city char(30),
last_update date(12) 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Comment: result: instead of expected number non numerical symbol was found. Due to MM - is 2 digits, representing number of month. So you solution failed

Comment: alter session set nls_date_language='american';

Comment: using SQL plus I altered session, but the same error remains. Maybe DATA format and 'DD-MON-YYYY' differ and conversion needed?

Comment: data file contains records like this one:

5001,1001,7,Atlanta,01-FEB-2004 - see in my question

Comment: The `alter session` won't change anything because SQL*Loader creates a separate connection (you can't specify the `alter session` in the control file). This must be controlled through an environment variable.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I used Oracle manager to edit spfile and to set nls parameters but still error appears and I can`t import data to the table

Comment: select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter like '%DATE%'; show query result

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have specified 12 number in date : `last_update date(12) 'DD-MON-YYYY'` in your control file, thats incorrect.

You should have it as `last_update date 'DD-MON-YYYY'`

SO control file shld be:

```
LOAD DATA
infile 'E:\labs\labs\lab_18_06.dat'
INTO TABLE INVENTORY.PRODUCT_ON_HAND
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(on_hand_id,
product_id,
quantity,
warehouse_city char(30),
last_update date 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Comment: no, this isn`t a issue, as after I made changes, that you advised, still the same error appears.